# Confused on Injection and Surjection Question - Not sure how to justify

Tags: functions

Given an arbitrary set $A$, let $f : A \rightarrow\wp(A)$, be the function defined for all $a\in A$ by "$f(a) = \{a\}$"

- Is $f$ injective?
- Is $f$ surjective?

I am struggling with this question.

How am i able to identify if the function is injective? Can somebody give an example?

What confuses me is the function "f(a) = {a}"

Comment: Does $f(a)=f(b)$ imply here that $a=b$?

Comment: I get the concept of injection but this particular question isn't making sense I'm not sure how to justify if this one is injective or surjective

Comment: Add to your question in what sense it "isn't making sense" in your view. I really can't find out what you mean by that.

Comment: A function $f$ is injective if $f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$. So by proving that you identify it as an injective function.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand this, but can you explain what is meant by "f(a) = {a}"?

Comment: $f:A\rightarrow B$ a function means that every $a\in A$ corresponds with exactly one $b\in B$. This $b$ is denoted as $f(a)$, so that $f(a)\in B$. In your question $B$ is the powerset of $A$ and contains subsets of $A$. The expression $f(a)=\{a\}$ tells you that the unique element corresponding with $a\in A$ is the element $\{a\}\in B=\wp A$. It is a prescription of function $f$. If you want to adress me in a comment then first type @ and then drhab. Then I receive a message.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

- Is it correct to conclude that $a=b$ if $\{a\}=\{b\}$?
- Can you find an $a\in A$ with $f(a)=\emptyset$?